# vmd does not open with filename in the command line argument in Mac OS X

Tags: linux, macos, macos-sierra, vmd

I have recently shifted from Linux to Mac OS. I have installed vmd in this new machine. The vmd just load without any molecule when I type the following:

```
vmd protein.gro
```

This *.gro file contains a protein molecule. I want to open this file like in Linux:

```
*applicationname filename*
```

But it doensnt work. Launching the molecule via vmd just simply doesnt work. I have tried to google this problem but I couldnt find the right answer. Is there anybody who had the same problem and was able to tackle it ?

Comment: Where did you get `vmd` from and how did you install it?

Comment: vmd is not a native tool for Mac. I have downloaded it from its website.

Answer (score 2):

Probably a little late but anyway. You only need to add a line to your bash_profile file.

The bash_profile file is located in:

```
/Users/user-name/.bash_profile
```

(remember to change user-name to your real username and note the dot at the beginning of the file's name)

inside the .bash_profile (or .profile) file add:

```
alias vmd='csh /Applications/VMD\ 1.9.3.app/Contents/MacOS/startup.command.csh'
```

(for a different version of VMD you will need to change the number (1.9.3) in the path to your actual VMD version). Save and close.

After this just source your .bash_profile (or .profile) file again so the changes are incorporated to your shell or just open a new terminal window.

Now you can type:

```
vmd my-gro-file.gro
```

just like in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Is vmd a native Mac app? If so, you should be able to use `open -a /path/to/vmd.app filename`.

Comment: I think the problem is more like `vmd /path/to/protein.gro` or `vmd ~/Downloads/protein.gro`.

Comment: I have tried both the options, but they did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the application itself, but maybe try this. First, find where the application is installed using the Terminal like this:

```
which vmd
```

and you should get the path to it. Then use the path like this:

```
open -a /path/to/vmd --args someMolecule.gro
```